# asciidoctor not run (or not running properly) in gradle

Tags: gradle, asciidoctor

I am having trouble getting the asciidoctor to run in gradle. The script is below.

```
asciidoctor {
    logger.lifecycle("Processing from $sourceDir to $asciiDocOutputDir")
    sources {
        include 'index.adoc'
    }
    backends = ['html5']
    attributes = [
            doctype: 'book',
            toc: 'left',
            toclevels: '3',
            numbered: '',
            sectlinks: '',
            sectanchors: '',
            hardbreaks: '',
            generated: asciiDocOutputDir
    ]
}
```

Here is the printout from the debug line to show the directories:

Processing from C:\Users\xxx\eclipse-workspace\springfox\src\docs\asciidoc to C:\Users\xxx\eclipse-workspace\springfox\build\asciidoc\generated

With the above logging line printed, does it mean the asciidoctor task was run? I don't see error and the index.html was not created (or at least I could not find it in the folder I expect to see it).

I have an index.adoc file under:
C:\Users\xxx\eclipse-workspace\springfox\src\docs\asciidoc\index.adoc with this content:

```
include::{generated}/overview.adoc[]
include::{generated}/paths.adoc[]
include::{generated}/security.adoc[]
include::{generated}/definitions.adoc[]
```

The 4 .adoc files are available in the following folder with contents:
C:\Users\xxx\eclipse-workspace\springfox\build\asciidoc\generated

But I could not get the index.html created :-(.  There is got to be a silly mistake somewhere but I just could not figure out.  What should I look for, or how can I debug this?

Thanks!

Comment: I have one update. I could get the asciidoctor task to run separately, meaning I ran gradlew clean build, and then run gradlew asciidoctor. The index.html could be created.  So I guess this is more of a gradle scripting issue. Why couldn't the asciidoctor task run when I ran the build task? You can see I am not experienced at gradle at all :-).

Comment: Call me stupid!  I should just have just run 'gradlew asciidoctor' and add a dependency on the test target. Everything is working!